# MathsJax in HTML Page

Tags: mathjax

i used mathjax in HTML page , it works. but a problem related to fontsize exist.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>

<title> mathsjax</title>
</head>
<body>
\(x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25}\)
$$x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25}$$
</body>
</html>
```

why in the first syntax[(x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25})] , fontsize is very small. and what to do to increase its size.

In addition, what is the difference between the two syntax's

`\(x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25}\)` .........1

`$$x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25}$$` .........2

Comment: For the font size issue try adding a live sample. Most likely, you're missing the correct viewport tags, cf. http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html

Comment: but , i'm using HTML ckeditor , which has TEx that allows us to maths figure and it is taking only inline expressions. therefore when i see in frontend , the size is very small. 

what is the solution to this problem.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\(` for inline math, and `\[` as equivalent of `$$`.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>

<title> mathsjax</title>
</head>
<body>
This is part of the line: \(x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25}\). Those are not:
\[x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25}\]
$$x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25}$$
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

If it isn't enough you can also add `\large` or `\huge`.

In his comments OP says he is using [HTML ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets), I suppose with the Mathematical Formulas widget. You can locate the demo of that widget in page linked and modify its source adding the following code:

```
<p><span class="math-tex">\( x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25}\)</span></p>

<p><span class="math-tex">\[ x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25}\]</span></p>

<p><span class="math-tex">\[ \large { x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25} } \]</span></p>

<p><span class="math-tex">\[ \huge { x={72^2-{\sqrt{53^2}}\over 25} } \]</span></p>
```

This should be the result:

[image: formulas]
​

Comment: but , i'm using HTML ckeditor , which has TEx that allows us to maths figure and it is taking only inline expressions. therefore when i see in frontend , the size is very small. 

what is the solution to this problem.

Comment: @learner please see the update. What browser are you using? IE (expecially the mobile version) has several issues with relative font sizing.

Comment: @learner if this has answered your question, please consider accepting it

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I'll update soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{\displaystyle{...}}` to force an expression or subexpression to use the sizes and spacing that would be used for a displayed equation.  For fractions in particular, if you have the AMSmath extension loaded, you can use `\dfrac{}{}` in place of `\frac{}{}` to get a fraction in display style.